# display date independent of system locale and as per the application language

Tags: javascript, datetime, locale

My web application supports two languages: English & French in which date is displayed in the header of each page.

Now, what happening is date is displayed as per the the user system's locale.If the end user system locale is Slovakia then date is displayed in slovakia.If it is English then it will be displayed in English. No matter in which language the web application is running English or French. This is because I am using

```
dateString.toLocaleString()
```

Below is the code:

```
var reg = new RegExp("[,]+", "g");
var tableau = theDate.split(reg);               
var value = new Date(tableau[0], (parseInt(tableau[1], 10) - 1), tableau[2], tableau[3], tableau[4], tableau[5]);
return value.toLocaleString();
```

where theDate is the comma separated string that contains month, day, year, time(like `10.21,2012,51,50,32`)

Now, my concern is I want to show the date in the format in which my application is running. If it is running in French then it should be displayed in french or if in English then it should be displayed in English. Independent of user system's locale.

Current date format is(in English locale): `Thursday, April 25, 2013 5:28:59 PM`
For other locale, day and month will get convert accordingly.

If I use `value.toString()` then it is displayed in this format

`Thu Apr 25 2013 17:28:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

that I do not want. I want to display in the current format but as per the application language(en/fr).

Please provide valuable suggestions.

Comment: check this link may be this will be helpful to you http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same answer I gave here a few hours ago: [JavaScript - Get system short date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210058/javascript-get-system-short-date-format)
There's no perfect solution but as you want a fix format declared by you, I'd recommend either using `toISOString()` if it fits your needs, or `getUTCDate()`,  `getUTCMonth()` and `getUTCDay()` and concatenate these guys to a string of your choice.