# Display date as per client datetime format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, format, client

In my SharePoint web site I am using Jquery date time picker and displaying the dates on my pages. I want to initialize my datetime picker with some default date but in **CLIENT** machine's format and need the same while displaying the dates elsewhere in my site. I tried to  use .toLocaleString() in JavaScript but it did not solve the problem. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

check this other similar threads. It might help you:

[How format JavaScript Date with regard to the browser culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469436/how-format-javascript-date-with-regard-to-the-browser-culture)

[How to detect the user's locale date and time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548783/how-to-detect-the-users-locale-date-and-time-format)