# How to get date formats of client machine for a web application?

Tags: javascript, cookies, utc

In my web application, I need to retrieve the client side date formats (Both Long and Short) and need to add it in the cookie. I will retrieve this value from the cookie from the server side. Am assuming, the only possible way is through JavaScript and but am not able to find any solution for it. Any pointers will be helpful.

Note: I don't need to just display the time in client format. Instead, i need to get the format itself. Am able to handle time zone properly and this is nothing related to time zone.

please see the attached image, for what I am exactly looking for.
[image: Date format in client windows machine]

Comment: Wiil any answers from here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548783/how-to-detect-the-users-locale-date-and-time-format

Comment: Would be to dangerous to let JavaScript accessing regedit (basically client machine configuration would be exposed to malicious users)