# Getting localized day of week

Tags: javascript, date, localization

I'd like to get the names of the days of the weeks in JavaScript, localized to the user's current language; preferably with something a bit nicer than what I'm using now:

```
var weekDays = [];
var d = new Date();

while(d.getDay() > 0) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}

while(weekDays.length < 7) {
    weekDays.push(d.toLocaleDateString().match(/\w+/)[0]);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or am I just going to have to provide date strings for as many locales as I can?

Comment: I cannot think of any other way of doing it, but if you are just storing the days of the week, you can just initialize the date to a Monday instead of going through the first while loop. Then loop through each day of the week and cache those values inside of the weekdays array.

Comment: I'd like to warn you that `toLocaleDateString` does not seem to be reliable. I'm on a Dutch version of Windows and Chrome, yet I get an array of English weekday names.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Standard way to translate `Date` is to use method `Date.toLocaleString()`, for example:

```
d = new Date();
// short date in browser language
d.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, {weekday: 'short'});
// long date in specific language
d.toLocaleString('sk-SK', {weekday: 'long'});
```

Comment: Huh! Although I was using that in the question, I never knew it took arguments! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at datejs, it handles localization very nicely. It comes with a lot of globalization setups. You just load the globalization setup of your current CultureInfo and datejs takes care of the rest.

[Javascript Date Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555353/javascript-date-localization)