# Find the day of the week in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially, I had it so that I made selects with the days of the week on the php page, and separate functions for them in the script

```html
<select id="dayofweek" onchange="filterTimes()">
  <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
  <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
  <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
  <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
  <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
  <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
  <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
</select>
```

```js
function filterTimes() {
  let dayofweek = document.getElementById("dayofweek").value;
    if ((["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"].indexOf(dayofweek) >= 0)) {
      let workHours = getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurantID, dayofweek);
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-height-fixed li a");
      for (let item of items) {
        let itemValue = parseFloat(item.getAttribute('data-value'));
        item.parentNode.classList[((itemValue < parseFloat(workHours.open)) || (itemValue > parseFloat(workHours.close)) ? "add" : "remove")]("invisible");
      }
    }
}
```

But I want not to use this select on php page but do everything in script, can i also define day of week not on php page but on js page in my general initialization function?

That is also to receive the value of each day. The function itself will look like this:

```js
let restaurantReserve = {
    workTime: null,
    id: null,
    init: function (json, restaurantID) {
        let _self = this;
        _self.workTime = json;
        _self.id = restaurantID;

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({startDate: '+0d'}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            $('#dayofweek').val(arDate[0]);
            filterTimes();
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });
    },

    getWorkHours: function (json, restaurant_id) {
      return json.filter(item => item.restaurant_id == restaurant_id);
    },
    
    getWorkHoursForDay: function (json, restaurant_id, day) {
      return getWorkHours(json, restaurant_id).filter(item => item.day === day)[0];
    },
    
    filterTimes: function () {
    let dayofweek = document.getElementById("dayofweek").value;
    if ((["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"].indexOf(dayofweek) >= 0)) {
      let workHours = getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurantID, dayofweek);
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-height-fixed li a");
      for (let item of items) {
        let itemValue = parseFloat(item.getAttribute('data-value'));
        item.parentNode.classList[((itemValue < parseFloat(workHours.open)) || (itemValue > parseFloat(workHours.close)) ? "add" : "remove")]("invisible");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create a variable with a list like:

```js
let dayofweek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

And define the day:

```js
let dayofweekAtIndex1 = dayofweek[1];
```

But how do I get it all to work in a function?

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use an array lookup for this problem. However, you should start the day of the week on Sunday to match the JavaScript Date.getDay method which returns Sun=0 though Sat=6. You could optionally use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) on the index `i % 7` to handle values greater than 6, i.e., so that it wraps around. And if it needs to be international then see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763761/getting-localized-day-of-week) on how to get the localized day of week.

```js
let dayofweek = i => ['Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][i % 7];


// test

console.log("Today is: " + dayofweek(new Date().getDay()));

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(i, dayofweek(i));
```

Comment: But how can I determine this day in the `filterTimes` function itself, how to understand which day I have chosen? everything is clear with the select, but how is it

Comment: @Krol - Your question is unclear, but I think you want to use the Date returned from your datepicker control.  Then use the above function like dayofweek(e.date.getDay())