# How to compare date with sever date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am working on online quiz so for main quiz questions i want to add on condition that checks users system date time and server date time if it match then quiz should be start, can anyone know how to do this.
please response if anyone knows about it

Comment: that sounds very problematic unless your server and all your users happen to share a timezone, probably UTC+0

Comment: even though i doesn't get how to do it. i have asign a task and i ho complete it!. what to do?

Answer (score 1):

There you go to catch the client date. [Javascript Date Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555353/javascript-date-localization)

You can use this and pull this information via ajax to your server and validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as you are doing a web application, so the DateTime.Now in your back-end code is already the DateTime of server.
So the problem now is how to get the datetime of client pc.

What I can come out with at the moment is :

1. Create hidden filed in your page

   Assume you are using ASP.NET, you can just give your input control a `runat="server"` 
   attribute like any other server side control.
2. Before you submit the quiz, update the filed using js
3. The server can then read it when the form posts back.
4. Compare the time with your server time to do any logic you want

Comment: That is how I would do it. On the first visit to the page I would run a bit of javascript in the page load event to determine the machine's date/time and stick it in a hidden field, and click a button to post back. You grab the time when the page posts back and, the second time the page loads, you have the info available server side. I do this all the time to determine the size of a user's screen. It's an extra visit to and from the server, but it usually takes place so quickly you don't even notice it in the browser.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse great explanation, martin!